# Notation for the size of a family of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Consider the family of sets $F = \{S_1, \dots, S_m\}$ $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}$, where $S_i$ is a set of elements $\forall i \leq m$. Let us define $C \subseteq F$.

Is there any convention for the notation of the size of $C$ (i.e. the number of sets in $C$)?

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: Isn't the operator $|\cdot|$ a measure of the "number of elements of the set"? However, in this case I am rather interested in the "number of sets of the family of sets"

Comment: A set can be an element of another set. In particular, $S_1$ and $S_2$ and .,.. and $S_m$ are the element of your $F$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $C$ is a family of sets, especially a finite family, then $C$ is just a set of sets. Therefore $|C|$ works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen $\lvert F \rvert, F^=,F\!\!\!{}^{{}^{{}^{\large{=}}}}$ and $\operatorname{card}(F)$ for the cardinality of $F.$

In some contexts (finite combinatorics?), $\#F$ or $\#(F)$ might be used.